# Static class reference name

Tags: c#, static

This is mostly just a question of curiosity. I've tried searches like "static class shorthand" or "static class nickname" and the like, and haven't found anything, which leads me to believe it isn't possible.

Let's say there's a static class called `TransitionalTransactionDeltaTemporaryRecord`. Is there a way in C# to create a shorter-named reference to said class in my code, such that I could use the reference in place of the class? Pseudo-code example below.

```
staticref DeltaRecord = System.TransitionalTransactionDeltaTemporaryRecord;

Transaction test = new Transaction();

// Ideally, these two would accomplish the same thing
test.Epsilon = DeltaRecord.ComputeEpsilon(pi);
test.Epsilon = TransitionalTransactionDeltaTemporaryRecord.ComputeEpsilon(pi);
```

I'm hoping to avoid having to use extremely long identifiers, if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the [type alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) everyone else is recommending. The alias is supposed to be used to disambiguate between two types with the same name, so solve naming conflicts. It's not supposed to be used for readability. In fact, it'll only confuse the user - he'll think `ShortName` is an actual type, which it isn't. Also, the alias is kinda useless, since it's only valid for *that* source file. IMO, it reduces readability, instead of increasing.

Comment: I can see the point @dcastro but I am not going to lie that name is pretty long. One of the points of Aliases and using directives is to shorten and make code more readable.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama true, the name really is horrible. But shouldn't the type itself be renamed then? I doubt the name *needs* to be that long..

Comment: I agree @dcastro I think it was an example OP invented for the discussion. But, sometimes you may be using code out of your control etc. It is an important feature to know about, but more importantly know how to not abuse it. *Great power and all that*

Comment: It was indeed a contrived example, but I have encountered class names like this before, in code that I had no control over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alias `using ShortName = System.TransitionalTransactionDeltaTemporaryRecord;` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a using directive (at the top of the file); for example:

```
using Dict = Dictionary<string, List<int>>;
```

Also, in C# 6, we will be able to use "static imports";

```
using System.Console;
...
WriteLine("Text"); //Instead of Console.WriteLine("Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can do this with your using directives.

`using TTDTR = TransitionalTransactionDeltaTemporaryRecord;`

***EDIT***:

Rename you class if you can though. Using a readability feature to get around a poor name isn't the best decision to make. What is the point of `Transactional` `Transaction`? Are there non transactional transactions? I realize this is probably your example class and not real but I find it rare that class names are so long that an alias is necessary. And if so, be carful to not muck up your code more and **be very sure** your alias doesn't map to another class.

Comment: Irrelevant since it was in fact simply an example, but it's `Transitional Transaction` rather than `Transactional Transaction`, just to clarify. Regardless, point taken.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `using` statement:

```
 using shortName = A.B.C.ClassName;
```